# Symfony2: inject services into non-services

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, code-injection

I come from the JEE world, where we can get references to services from anywhere in the code... Is it also possible with Symfony? Because passing many services as parameter is boring and sometimes you have no choice...

Eg: I have a recursive form that I cannot declare as service, in which I use listeners => services used by listeners must be passed from the controller to the form and then to the listeners...

Except using the &kernel (from which you can get the service container)...

Comment: This question looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/237701), Please describe what you're trying to do with an example of code.

Comment: Just a general question, I have many examples like the one I gave. Another example is when a use an non-service object that do a treatment and needs a service.

Comment: why you can't define your form  as a service?

Comment: My form is recursive, it is built dynamically from information get in DB and their might be subform ; all forms being based on the same Type. So if it were a service, I could only have one instance.

Answer (score 0):

To get a reference to a service in Symfony2 you must use the service container. If you are in a controller you have direct access to every service by doing `$this->container->get('service_name');`. If you are in another class, then you must inject your dependencies into that class, or inject the service container directly if passing too many arguments to a constructor is not your thing.